# iPhone's Page Control Error

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

> Ld "/Users/waitonza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dr_Ngoo-aanknxmuodcgjicaigxevljxokeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dr
>   Ngoo.app/Dr Ngoo" normal i386
>       cd /Users/waitonza/Desktop/Project/Dr-Ngoo
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/waitonza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dr_Ngoo-aanknxmuodcgjicaigxevljxokeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/waitonza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dr_Ngoo-aanknxmuodcgjicaigxevljxokeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist "/Users/waitonza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dr_Ngoo-aanknxmuodcgjicaigxevljxokeq/Build/Intermediates/Dr
>   Ngoo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dr Ngoo.build/Objects-normal/i386/Dr
>   Ngoo.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker
>   -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o
>   "/Users/waitonza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dr_Ngoo-aanknxmuodcgjicaigxevljxokeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dr
>   Ngoo.app/Dr Ngoo"
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PagingScrollViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DrNgooAppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What changes did you make in that sample? Also, do you have multiple `PagingScrollViewController` classes?

Comment: I didn't change anything except the delegate class to my application one. I double checked and there's only one `PagingScrollViewController`

Comment: Changing the delegate name won't cause problems. The error indicates that `PagingScrollViewController` was not found or is duplicated(which you say is not the case). Did you `#import "PagingScrollViewController.h"` in your `delegate.h` class?

Comment: It would be better if you could upload the project for people to look at!

Comment: @tipycalFlow here you go https://github.com/waitonza/Dr-Ngoo

Comment: I checked your project and it does not have `PagingScrollViewController`. You're probably referencing it from outside the folder. Add it to the project too!

Comment: @tipycalFlow can you post an answer to this? So I can accept your answer? ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the same as we've discussed in the comments:

`I checked your project and it does not have PagingScrollViewController. You're probably referencing it from outside the folder. Add it to the project too and it should work fine!`

@CodaFi also had the correct answer so +1 to him too!

Answer (score 1):

The class PagingScrollViewController is not in your compile list.  In the file tree, click your project at the top, then go to your target>build phases expand 'compile phase', then drag the PagingScrollViewController.m file to the list and run.

Comment: It's in there, I have already search for this problem and tried this solution already.

Comment: Does the file appear in the list in red or black?

Comment: Did you do what typicalFlow said and #import and @class the file?

Comment: this is the delegate file
`

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DrNgooDatabaseViewController.h"
#import "PagingScrollViewController.h"

@class PagingScrollViewController;

@interface DrNgooAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *rootViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *settingInfo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PagingScrollViewController *pagingScrollViewController;

@end`

Comment: I can't honestly figure out what's wrong with the github code.... And you do seem to be linking to the proper frameworks... Copy the file, delete it, then make a duplicate.